# Paginated Report-Export to PDF not showing symbols

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a Paginated Report for which I am have the up and down small triangle symbols in a column.  They show up fine when I run the report as well as when I export to Excel, but when I export to PDF, they show up as empty squares.  I define the symbols using the ChrW(9650) and ChrW(9660).  I set the font family to " ".  Any suggestions on how to get this to export correctly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try following fonts:

- Segoe UI Symbol
- Lucida Sans Unicode
- Arial Unicode MS